# Access Azure Key Vault in Pandas read/write Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, azure-databricks

Recently, Microsoft released a way for Pandas to read/write Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 data in serverless Apache Spark pool in Synapse Analytics as per the below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool

If I have to use the same strategy for pyspark in Azure DataBricks, how can I use the datalake secret (from Azure Key Vault) containing the account key so that pandas can access the data lake smoothly? In this way, I don't have to expose the secret value in DataBricks notebook

Answer (score 0):

for Azure Databricks you just need to [create a secret scope out of the Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#--create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope), and then you can use `dbutils.secrets.get` function to [retrieve a secret from secret scope or ingest the secrets into a Spark conf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#read-a-secret).

Please note that you will need to set correct Spark configuration to use that storage account key refer to documentation for details ([blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-directly), [ADLS Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/))